# 3D chess application in android

Tags: android, chess, uci

I wrote a 3D chess application in android using OpenGLES. It doesn't have any intelligence except for basic chess piece movement rules.
For now , it is a 2 player game human vs human. Now i want to include any open source chess engine so that it can support computer vs human also.
But I am clueless how to go about it. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you only need to implement one of two (or both) protocoles: [UCI](http://www.shredderchess.com/chess-info/features/uci-universal-chess-interface.html) or [WinBoard](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/engine-intf.html). Then you can communicate with any chess engine.